# Chrome extension, create a new tab based on asynchronous fetched data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm struggling with the behavior of `chrome.tabs.create()`.

Here's what I hope to achieve: after clicking the button, the app can fetch a URL, then create a new tab based on the `messageUrl` we just fetched.

Thank you in advance!

Here's my code (doesn't work)

- `popup.html`

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <body style="width: 200px;">
      <form>
        <button id="myButton">Open a random url</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```
- `popup.js`

  ```js
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', documentEvents, false);

  // fetch a URL and return a string (which is also a URL)
  async function getMessageUrl() {
    const res = await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random');
    const json = await res.json();
    return await json['message'];
  }

  async function openImageUrl() {
    const messageUrl = await getMessageUrl();
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: messageUrl });
  }

  function documentEvents() {
    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
      openImageUrl();
    });
  }
  ```

Comment: document.getElementById('myButton') where is myButton?

Comment: Hi @NadiaChibrikova, sorry it was a typo. I've fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news: seems like you can't await asynchronous calls inside the popup.
Good news: you can await them in the background script, so you can move your function there and call it from the popup like this

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().openImageUrl();
```